# How to get PR dependencies from Gitea API

Tags: api, version-control, gitea

I want to get list of blocking dependencies from a PR request through Gitea API.

I searched through the internet and API documentation, but I didn't find any solution.

For adding a blocking dependency to a PR Gitea uses an api call to /{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{index}/dependency/add

For deleting /{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{index}/dependency/delete

These routes are not documented in Gitea API documentation.